# How to forward image from internal REST service

Tags: django, rest, tomcat

I have a Django site which will include some media in the form of images, audio and video. My media will most likely be fetched from an internal object storage REST API which is not accessible to the outside.

I've made a quick prototype where there's a Django view callable at /objects/ which in turn calls the internal object storage REST API and returns the object. The media is all served using HTML5 tags.

How can I best  forward the call to my internal REST API without introducing performance problems by having everything go through Django? It might work fine to go with my existing solution but I'm a bit apprehensive about serving large files like this. Is there a better way? I call the internal service's REST API through a 3rd party python library which handles authentication etc. The site will likely run on a Tomcat server in production if that matters.

The site is not expected to have very much traffic, but the video files may be quite large.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood you correctly - a common approach for delivering files via REST is to deliver URIs pointing to the files. I should be up to the client how to retrieve them. This saves you also from performance issues.

Comment: The problem is that the REST service isn't visible to the outside world so I need to forward the request unless I can convince them to open it up.